# Countif sum formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to create a formula that looks at the first row of of a table, runs a countif, then multiple that value by constant.

It then looks at the 2nd row, runs the countif, the multiples it by a 2nd value.

I know i can run multiple countif * X + countif * Y etc, but for the data I am using, its a bit too big.

I've tried using an array formula;

```
={COUNTIF(OFFSET($B$2:$U$10,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},0,1,COLUMNS($B$2:$U$10)),A29)*{$V$2,$V$3,$V$4,$V$5,$V$6,$V$7,$V$8,$V$9,$V$10}
```

So this is trying to countif B2 to U2 is the same as A29 then multiple by V2, Then add B3 to U3 compared to A30 then multiple by V3.

Excel just says there is a problem with the formula and refuses to even try to fix it.

I hope this is clear. I think my problem is using arrays with countif's, but I am unsure

Comment: For sure, you are missing the last bracket `}` to close the formula. But you should paste this `=COUNTIF(OFFSET($B$2:$U$10,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},0,1,COLUMNS($B$2:$U$10)),A29)*{$V$2,$V$3,$V$4,$V$5,$V$6,$V$7,$V$8,$V$9,$V$10}` and then press Ctrl+Shit+Enter

Comment: Ah oops, thanks for the heads-up

Still doesn't work.  When it errors, and i hit OK to fix, it highlights the $B$2 after the columns function. Does that mean anything?

Comment: You will probably need a helper column to make this work.

Comment: What about `=COUNTIF(OFFSET($B$2:$U$2,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},0,1,COLUMNS($B$2:$U$2)),A29)*{$V$2,$V$3,$V$4,$V$5,$V$6,$V$7,$V$8,$V$9,$V$10}`?

Comment: nope still doesn't work. I suspect it is because it is within the offset and countif, because this also doesn't work:
`=SUM(IF(OFFSET($B$2:$U$10,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},0,1,COLUMNS($B$2:$U$10))=A29,1,0))*{V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10}
    I guess Scott's answer may have to do. Shame, i really wanted an awesome formula to show off with.

Comment: Also tried changing how the array was inserted with: =SUM(IF(OFFSET($B$2:$U$10,{0:8},0,1,COLUMNS($B$2:$U$10))=A29,1,0))*{V2:V10}

Comment: This should be at least close to what you are trying to do : `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$U$10)=($A$29:$A$37);($V$3:$V$10))`

Comment: Still nope... running into #N/A and I can't see where they are coming from. Thanks for the help. Good to know that my questions are really good when i run into trouble

Comment: @R3uK formula was close: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$U$10=$A$29:$A$37)*$V$2:$V$10)`

Comment: AH HA we have a winner... had to change it slightly to because I am comparing to only 1 value.
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$U$10=$A$29)*$V$2:$V$10)

Is that using boolean logic then matrix multiplication?

Comment: @ScottCraner : Thx for the correction, I'm doing to much coding and not enough Excel! BTW, I'd still recommend `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$U$10=$A$29:$A$37);$V$2:$V$10)` which will overlook eventual errors from the test part (ie type mysmatch)

Comment: whats the difference with the semi colon?

Add yours in too and ill put correct answer

Comment: @R3uK then you will need to change it slightly: `=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$U$10=$A$29:$A$37);$V$2:$V$10)`  the Boolean needs to be changed to a bit.

Comment: @BryanDavies you will need to change the `;` to `,`.  It is a local setting.  By putting it in its own criterion it will do as R3uK states and ignore any errors, or text in column V.

Comment: @ScottCraner : Hmm, yeah! Forgot about `--`, working out of fading memories!^^ Could you include it in the wiki? I'll find the link explaining and add it! ;)

Comment: ah so by using the comma, you apply it to be used as an array within the sumproduct whereas the original one was multiplying within the sumproduct function and using the sumproduct basically as a sum? and using the -- forces it to be a number i assume?

Comment: @ScottCraner : Not finding what I had in mind (on msdn), this is the best I came across so far :http://crispexcel.com/sumproduct-the-most-powerful-function-in-excel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @R3uK's comment:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$U$10=$A$29)*$V$2:$V$10)
```

Column W is just to show it comes with the correct answer.

[image]

---

Also, If there is a chance that column V will contain errors or text by seperating them into their own criteria will skip those that have them:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$U$10=$A$29:$A$37);$V$2:$V$10)
```

The `--` changes the Boolean TRUE/FALSE to their bit equivalents 1/0 so it can then be multiplied to the results on column V.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Also in explaining the answer as well